# Prove $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{x-x_n^2}{2}, x_0 = 0$ is increasing and less than $\sqrt {x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{x-x_n^2}{2}, x_0 = 0$$ Then, prove that $0\le x_n\le x_{n+1}\le \sqrt{x}$ for $0\le x\le 1$

Comment: Is this true for $x_1$.

Comment: Any condition on $x$?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll prove that $x_n < \sqrt{x}$. Consider a function $f(t) = t + \dfrac{x-t^2}{2} = -\dfrac{t^2}{2} + t + \dfrac{x}{2}$. It is a simple quadratic equation, that is why it is increasing on $(-\infty; 1]$ and decreasing on $[1; +\infty)$. That means that if $0 \leq t \leq \sqrt{x}$ ($\sqrt{x} < 1$), than $f(0) \leq f(t) \leq f(\sqrt{x})$, meaning that $0 < \dfrac{x}{2} \leq f(t) \leq \sqrt{x}$.

Now we can use induction in order to prove that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ holds: $0 \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{x}$.

*Basis:* $0 \leq x_0 = 0 \leq \sqrt{x}$

*Step:* If it has been proved that $0 \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{x}$, than, because $f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$ it holds that $0 \leq x_{n+1} = f(x_n) \leq \sqrt{x}$.

---

$x_n$ is a bounded incresing sequence, that is why it has a limit. I'll denote it as A: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = A$. Consider a sequence $y_n = x_n + \dfrac{x - x_n^2}{2}$. Firstly, it can be seen that $y_n = x_{n+1}$, therefore $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = A$. Secondly, due to properties of limits we have: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x-x_n^2 = x - A^2$, that is why $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = A+\dfrac{x-A^2}{2}$.

So we end up with an equation: $A = A + \dfrac{x-A^2}{2}$, which has only one positive solution: $A = \sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_n\le 1$ then we see that
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} =\frac{x+2x_n-x_n^2}{2}= \frac{x+(2-x_n)x_n}{2} \le \frac{x+1}{2}\le 1.
\end{align}
Hence by induction, we see that $x_n\le 1$ for all $n$.
Next, observe if $x_{n-1}\le x_n$ then 
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-x_n = (x_n-x_{n-1})-\frac{x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2}{2} = (x_n-x_{n-1})\left(1-\frac{x_n+x_{n-1}}{2} \right) \ge 0
\end{align}
which means $x_n\le x_{n+1}$. Thus, by induction, we see that $x_n$ is monotone 
increasing.

Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{x-x_n^2}{2}= x_{n+1}-x_n\ge 0
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
x\ge x_n^2.
\end{align}
This completes the argument.